# Assigning events dynamically with a form that has no reference

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I've got a class where I pass in a panel reference and in that panel I'm then required to draw multiple other panels that represent my objects. The issue is that when I go to bind dynamically click events to these panels I don't have reference to the Form of which I want to popup on the click event.

The reason for this structure is so that I can redraw my class dynamically and reattach certain events to each object.

Is there any way to do this without moving my classes logic outside of the Assembly or is there any way to attach my click event to a piece of code logic to a sub in my WinForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to any control on a `Form` you can recursively navigate up the `Parent` property until you hit the `Form`. Just test that the parent property's type is assignable to a variable of type `Form`.